# Javascript Regular expression for range of six-digit base36 numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm building a node.js application and storing a six-digit base36 representation of a unix timestamp (in seconds) as the first part of an _id in Mongodb. A typical _id looks like this:

```
"_id" : "lwhlzy/czwszasfgr/a4d18976c1/f835caa1c3/184d06b47f"
```

Several pieces of data are concatenated, including the timestamp followed by a series of hashed data to form both a GUID and a "[materialized path](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB#TreesinMongoDB-MaterializedPaths%28FullPathinEachNode%29)"

Later queries will select records based on a time range, followed by the path to get events that happened during that period for that particular path. These queries will rely on [rooted regular expressions](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions), so I need a regex that can find a range of base36 numbers:

This is the code I have so far (a test to run via node and yes it is hard-coded to six digits. The seventh digit wont be needed until Dec 23rd 2038.)

```
var base36 = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

// determine how many left-most characters from & to have in common
// this function works nicely, no problems here
var getOverlap = function (from, to) {
    regex = '';
    count = to.length;

    for (i in to) {
        regex += (i>0?'|':'')+'('+to.slice(0,count)+')';
        count--;
    }

    result = from.match(RegExp(regex,"ig"));
    return result[0];
};

var from = "lec0s0"; 
var to = "lwhvqg"; // generated from: parseInt(Date.now()/1000,10).toString(36)

var overlap = getOverlap(from,to);

console.log(from);
console.log(to);

var regex = overlap;
var i = overlap.length;
// start immediately after the left-most common characters and append the rest of the regex
while (i<6) {
    regex += "[";

    if (from[i] < to[i]) {
        regex += base36.slice(base36.indexOf(from[i]), base36.indexOf(to[i])+1);
    } else {
        regex += base36.slice(base36.indexOf(from[i])) + base36.slice(0, base36.indexOf(to[i])+1);
    }

    regex += "]";
    i++;
}

console.log(regex);
process.exit();
```

Which will output something like this:

```
l[efghijklmnopqrstuvw][cdefgh][0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv][stuvwxyz0123456789abcdefghijklmnopq][0123456789abcdefg]
```

After studying this I realized there are two main issues with this: 1) its not quite right for a true range (it would skip huge chunks of records) and 2) Id rather have character ranges like `[e-w]` instead of every character explicitly stated though it still works.

For input `from="lec0s0"` and `to="lwhvqg"` I realize Im missing a large part of this regex. For example, the code above only allows the 3rd character a range from `c-h`, but that position will need to reach "z" before the 2nd character can increment. I've determined that I actually need a regex that looks more like this:

```
l[e-v][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z]|l[e-w][c-g][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z]|l[e-w][c-h][0-9a-u][0-9a-z][0-9a-z]|l[e-w][c-h][0-9a-v][0-9a-o][0-9a-z]|l[e-w][c-h][0-9a-v][0-9a-q][0-9a-g]
```

So my question is: am I right to conclude the regex needs to look like the latter above? And if so, how might I modify the code to generate it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current pattern will match from `le0000` and up, you actually wish to match:

```
lec0s[0-9a-z]|lec0[t-z][0-9a-z]{1}|lec[1-9a-z][0-9a-z]{2}|le[d-z][0-9a-z]{3}|l[f-v][0-9a-z]{4}|lw[0-9a-g][0-9a-z]{3}|lwh[0-9a-u][0-9a-z]{2}|lwhv[0-9a-p][0-9a-z]{1}|lwhvq[0-9a-g]
```

The following function should give you the regex you need:

```
function getRegex(from,to) {
    var base36 = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
        getRange = function(f,t) {
            if(f == t) {
                return f;
            }
            if(base36.indexOf(f) >= base36.indexOf(t)) {
                return t;
            } 
            if(t <= '9' || f >= 'a'){
                return '[' +f+'-'+t+']';
            }
            return '[' +f+(f<'9'?'-9':'')+(t>'a'?'a-':'')+t+']';    
        },
        from = from.split(''),
        to = to.split(''),
        prefix='', 
        regex=[], 
        tmp,i,l;

    for(i=0,l=from.length;i<l;i++) {
        if(from[i]!=to[i]) {
            break;
        }
        prefix+=from[i];
    }
    from.splice(0,prefix.length);
    to.splice(0,prefix.length);

    i = from.length;
    while(i--) {
        tmp = prefix+from.slice(0,i).join('');
        if(from[i] == 'z') {
            tmp+='z';
        }
        else if(from.length-i == 1) {
            tmp += getRange(from[i],'z');
        }
        else if(i) {
            tmp += getRange(base36.charAt(base36.indexOf(from[i])+1),'z');
            tmp += '[0-9a-z]{'+(from.length-i-1)+'}';
        } 
        else {
            tmp += getRange(base36.charAt(base36.indexOf(from[i])+1),base36.charAt(base36.indexOf(to[i])-1));
            tmp += '[0-9a-z]{'+(from.length-i-1)+'}';
        }
        regex.push(tmp);
    }
    for(i=1,l=to.length;i<l;i++) {
        tmp = prefix+to.slice(0,i).join('');
        if(to[i] == '0') {
            tmp+='0';
        }
        else if(to.length-i == 1) {
            tmp += getRange('0',to[i]);
        }
        else {
            tmp += getRange('0',base36.charAt(base36.indexOf(to[i])-1));
            tmp += '[0-9a-z]{'+(from.length-i-1)+'}';
        } 
        regex.push(tmp);
    }

    return regex.join('|');
}
```

You can see it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/3cu52/3/

Comment: Hey I'm getting this Error: "Range out of order in character class" for this Regex: "lwq0x[8-9a-z]|lwq0[y-z][0-9a-z]{1}|lwq[1-9a-z][0-9a-z]{2}|lw[r-q][0-9a-z]{3}|lwr[0-9a-u][0-9a-z]{2}|lwrv[0-9a-k][0-9a-z]{1}|lwrvl[0-8]" 

I think it's the "r-q" doing that. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: There was a missing check in `getRange` which has now been added. Look at my updated answer - i have also updated the fiddle, look for the line `if(base36.indexOf(f) >= base36.indexOf(t))`

Comment: Thanks Martin! Are you available for contract work? If interested, Im on the twitters @talentedmrjones

Answer (score 1):

I just want to point out a mistake in your pattern

```
l[e-v][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z]|l[e-w][c-g][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z]|l[e-w][c-h][0-9a-u][0-9a-z][0-9a-z]|l[e-w][c-h][0-9a-v][0-9a-o][0-9a-z]|l[e-w][c-h][0-9a-v][0-9a-q][0-9a-g]

l[e-v][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z]|lw[c-g][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z]|lwh[0-9a-u][0-9a-z][0-9a-z]| ...
                                        ^                               ^^
```

at the marked positions, you don't need to repeat the ranges, that unnecessary, because you covered the patterns starting with "le" in the first alternative.

Comment: Oh I see! Yes that makes perfect sense thank you! Any ideas on how to code that? Im sure I can get it but my brain is slowing down the closer we get to the holidays :)

Comment: sorry its time for bed in Germany. Normally I would say, Regex is not good at checking number ranges and you should extract the numbers and use the normal number comparators. But I have no idea if such a thing exists for base36.